# How do I count the largest number of unique entries in a single day in R?

Tags: r

I have some data from a Whatsapp chat export which looks like this:

```
time                 author             text               day     times     timeblock  dayblock
2019-08-02 12:16:40|"a65c9c3a"|"This message was deleted"  |2|   "12:16:40"| "Cycle 1"|  "No"
2019-08-02 12:36:40|"ab5c9c0a"|"Please take a survey"      |2|   "12:36:40"| "Cycle 1"|  "No"
2019-08-02 13:29:40|"43cd8b94"|"Done :D"                   |2|   "13:29:40"| "Cycle 1"|  "No"
2019-08-02 17:41:40|"083fa508"|"<Media omitted>"           |2|   "17:41:40"| "Cycle 1"|  "No"


str(chat)

Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  16111 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ time     : POSIXct, format: "2019-08-02 12:16:40" "2019-08-02 12:35:40" "2019-08-02 12:36:40" ...
 $ author   : chr  "ab5c9c0a" "ab5c9c0a" "ab5c9c0a" "43cd8b94" ...
 $ text     : chr  "This message was deleted" "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf4hE" "Please take a survey" "Done :D" ...
 $ day      : int  2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ times    : chr  "12:16:40" "12:35:40" "12:36:40" "13:29:40" ...
 $ timeblock: Factor w/ 13 levels "Cycle 1","Cycle 2",..:
```

What I wanted to try and see was on which single date did we encounter the largest number of unique authors, i.e, what topic were we talking about when the largest number of people had something to say.

Additionally, what I am also interested in seeing the opposite, and find out when date/time when only 4-5 `author`s produced most `text`.

I don't know how to proceed with this but I tried doing

```
chat %>% group_by(author, date) %>% count(date)
```

which I thought would count the individual dates which could be sorted, but this doesn't do that.

How can I do this?

```
This is what the sample looks like: 

                   time   author
 1: 2019-08-02 12:16:17 ab5c9c0a
 2: 2019-08-02 12:35:17 ab5c9c0a
 3: 2019-08-02 12:36:17 ab5c9c0a
 4: 2019-08-02 13:29:17 43cd8b94
 5: 2019-08-02 17:41:17 083fa508
 6: 2019-08-03 15:02:17 58d48a3a
 7: 2019-08-03 15:02:17 58d48a3a
 8: 2020-12-08 10:49:17 baf8b772
 9: 2020-12-09 09:59:17 6ee68966
10: 2020-12-09 14:43:17 9c342ce5
                                                                                                               text
 1:                                                                                        This message was deleted
 2:                                                                  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/-p-/viewform?usp=sf_link
 3:                                                                                            Please take a survey
 4:                                                                                                         Done :D
 5:                                                                                                 <Media omitted>
 6:                                                                                                 <Media omitted>
 7:                                                                             This guy was caught
 8:                                                                                     ^information overload class
 9:                                               People from class do y'all know where class is?
10:  Mobile Class\nFollow this link to join the WhatsApp group:
     day    times       date timeblock dayblock
 1:   2 12:16:17 2019-08-02   Cycle 1    12 PM
 2:   2 12:35:17 2019-08-02   Cycle 1    12 PM
 3:   2 12:36:17 2019-08-02   Cycle 1    12 PM
 4:   2 13:29:17 2019-08-02   Cycle 1    01 PM
 5:   2 17:41:17 2019-08-02   Cycle 1    05 PM
 6:   3 15:02:17 2019-08-03   Cycle 1    03 PM
 7:   3 15:02:17 2019-08-03   Cycle 1    03 PM
 8:   8 10:49:17 2020-12-08  No Event    10 AM
 9:   9 09:59:17 2020-12-09  No Event    09 AM
10:   9 14:43:17 2020-12-09  No Event    02 PM
```

Comment: In order to help you give a reproducible example with `dput` or the `reprex` package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your question:

> What I wanted to try and see was on which single date did we encounter
> the largest number of unique authors

```
chat %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  count(author) %>%
  arrange(-n)
```

For the second part of your question, I wouldn't `count` and instead use `mutate`:

> i.e, what topic were we talking about when the largest number of people had something to say.

```
chat %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  mutate(test = n_distinct(author)) %>%
  arrange(-test)
```

Comment: Just to be sure, the number in the `test` column is giving me the number of unique authors for that day right? I see the number repeating down the line and I was a little confused. Is there a way to collapse this and just have two columns `date` and `test` so that I can plot number of active users by date?

Comment: Never mind, I think I figured this out! Thank you so much, this is fantastic.

Comment: Yes, you could collapse this. Howeber, you wanted to have the topics discussed as well, and these differ by date/author. if you only want to keep data and number, it's easy to collapse. But since you figured this out, I won't update my post (also because there's still no example to work with).